# C# Close Popup in IE

Tags: c#, javascript, internet-explorer, popup

I have a popup that for changing your password, when the user clicks cancel the popup closes using java but when save is clicked it saves the new password then calls the java using `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript( this.GetType(), "close", "self.close()", true );`

but the pop up does not close it opens the page again telling the user that the page would like to close, which is fine but when you click OK the page closes but the first popup does not. does anyone know how to make the popup close? this is just a problem in IE works fine in chrome and other web browers

Edit -

```
function Close() {
            window.close();
            return false;
        }         
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnSave" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/buttons_save.gif"
                            OnClick="btnSave_Click" />

protected void btnSave_Click( object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e )
    {
        if( Page.IsValid )
        {
            try
            {
                Boolean confirm = User.ChangePassword( txtNewPassword.Text, var.UserId );
                if( confirm )
                {

                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript( this.GetType(), "close", "self.close()", true );
                }
                else
                {
                    lblMessage.Text = "Attempt failed";
                }
            }
            catch( Exception ex )
            {
                Utilities.logError( ex );
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you post your HTML and JavaScript?

Comment: Can you post the HTML to the popup window? In your javascript you say window.close(); this is closing the main window.